# Bitmap Image read differently 32/64 bit build

Tags: c#, build, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitmapimage

EDIT:  This first part doesn't seem to be the problem, see below (thanks Ted and Jim):

This is part of a p-hash implementation.  The code runs well and consistently, but when compiled under 64 vs. 32 the results are slightly different for some images.  (averageValue is uint)

```
ulong hash = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
   if (grayscale[i] >= averageValue)
       {
           hash |= (1UL << (int)(63L - i));
       }
```

Compiled under VS2010.  Any ideas for changing the implementation?

### Thanks!

Edit:  The problem doesn't seem to be in that part, but in reading the image and condensing it.

I'm getting my images like so (image is a passed Bitmap Image):

```
        // Squeeze the image into an 8x8 canvas
        Bitmap squeezed = new Bitmap(8, 8, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(squeezed);
        canvas.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        canvas.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 8, 8);
```

and then in a nested for loop

```
uint pixel = (uint)squeezed.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb();
```

But these values differ:

4287269514
4290559164
4290559164
4289835184
4285687133
4285421390
4288056455
4290427578
4290559164
4294769916
....

vs:

4287335307
4290559164
4290559164
4289900719
4285752925
4285487183
4288121992
4290493371
4290559164
4294901502
....

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `grayscale` array has identical values when this code is executed in the 32- and 64-bit builds?

Comment: Not related to your question (?), but why have `(int)(63L - i)` instead of just `(63 - i)`?

Comment: That's pretty strange. In 64-bit the value is `47C7 E3C0 C100 0000`. In 32-bit it's `47C7 E3C0 C080 0000`. The difference is that the 32-bit version shifted one bit left less than the 64-bit version. Could the difference be in the image bytes? Are you perhaps getting the raw image bits and not taking padding into account?

Comment: Are `grayscale[i]` and `averageValue` of floating-point type and the result of floating-point calculations? Can't you just check the 64 comparisons, actually Jim's comment shows which `i` in the loop disagrees ...

Comment: Ted:  It turns out no, the grayscale array is not the same, there are some slight differences.  Combined with Jim it's correct, a shift is missing because of these different values (not a padding issue, though).  I'll update the question- it is still odd that the grayscale array should change depending on the build.